# Ruby on Rails pass form variables to controller

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, copy, carrierwave, duplicate-data

When a form is submitted, it passes these parameters.

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"copyfile",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yM2v0dJysGuw7zRIhuhY7xHMywuDRjfBqzpJc0/LCqE=",
 "redocument"=>{"odocument_id"=>"14"},
 "commit"=>"Update Redocument",
 "method"=>"copyfile",
 "id"=>"66"}
```

I would like to reference to the `odocument_id` in the parameters passed within the controller.

Within my controller I have this

```
  def copyfile
    @oldfile = Redocument.find(params[:id])
    @newfile = Redocument.find(params[:id]).dup

    @newfile.odocument_id = params[:odocument_id]
    if @newfile.save!
      dupfile(@oldfile.redocument.to_s, @newfile.redocument.to_s)
      flash[:notice] = 'Record was successfully cloned.'
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Record ERROR: Item can\'t be cloned.'
    end

    redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

I have it successfully creating the file within the new ID folder. However, I am categorizing my directory structure like odocument_id/redocument_id/. I cannot get the odocument_id to update prior to calling the function dupfile to create the folders and copies. When I see the @newfile upload into MySQL, it creates a NULL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the :odocument_id parameter properly. As you can see in the obtained parameters `"redocument"=>{"odocument_id"=>"14"}`, "odocument_id" is within the "redocument" parameter. So you need to do it like this:

```
@newfile.odocument_id = params[:redocument][:odocument_id]
```

You were doing `params[:odocument_id]` which doesn't exist so you were getting the null value.

Also, you can just do

```
@newfile = @oldfile.dup
```

and don't need to find the file again.

Comment: Thanks Dipil. That worked. I had that "exact" line before, but must have had a type-o. Sometimes I make redundant calls like refinding the @newfile to just make things work out in my head.